# check if a range is empty using excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

It seems like "application.worksheetfunction.CountA(range) = 0" works for everyone but me to check if a range is empty.

I opened a new excel sheet and put 23 in E2. That's all I did. And below is the code that I used to test the method.

```
Sub test()
MsgBox Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet1.Columns("A:D"))
MsgBox Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet1.Columns("A:E"))
End Sub
```

I got 156 instead of 0 from the first msgbox and 197 from the second msgbox.

Any idea why?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the new Excel sheet definitely Sheet1? This is a whole new workbook?

Comment: ^^ and your code is expecting the sheet to have a `CodeName` of `Sheet1`, not just a `Name` of `"Sheet1"`.

Comment: Did you have any other Excel files open at the same time? if so, what module did you place the code in, and in what **VBAProject**? (top-left pane). Try it again, after closing Excel completely and opening just one file

Comment: Thanks everyone! Sorry for not being able to get back to you sooner. I reopened the workbook and it works fine now. I will try it in the project that I'm working on now.